# warning message{ In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion } in R during plotting?

Tags: r

```
plot1 <- plot(mydata2[, 1], mydata2[, 2], xlab = "year", ylab = "daily totals (gwh)", type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "orange", xlim = c(2006, 2018), ylim = c(840, 1750), main = "consumption graph")
```

Warning message:

`In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput(mydata2)`?

Comment: This is an error that is usually seen when you have numbers stored in character format. Try `plot(as.numeric(mydata2[,1]),as.numeric(mydata2[,2]),xlab = "year",ylab = "daily totals (gwh)",type="l",lwd=2,col="orange",xlim=c(2006,2018),ylim=c(840,1750),main="consumption graph")`

Comment: Try to make R guess the correct formats `mydata2 <- type.convert(mydata2, as.is=TRUE)` then plot again.

Comment: i am  very  tense cause i try all the three method one by one but all  in vain still get the same warning error @https://stackoverflow.com/users/14282714/https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameronquinten@https://stackoverflow.com/users/6574038/jay-sf

Comment: { 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, }
https://stackoverflow.com/users/14282714/quinten        with dput(mydata2) i am getting this sort of data and i dont know why it add L with all the data

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg